# Visual Studio stops debugging when SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar() is executed

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ado.net

I have this code in my application

```
SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

sqlConnection1.Open();

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT S2 FROM CDUSR WHERE N100 = " + N100.ToString()  ;

var HashStr = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
sqlConnection1.Close();
```

When I reach at the line

```
var HashStr = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Visual Studio 2015 stops debugging my application without any error.

`connectionString` contains a valid connection string (I have tested)

This query `SELECT S2 FROM CDUSR WHERE N100 = 6369` executes successfully in SSMS.

I want to know what the problem is. S2 contains the following string:

```
a4sd4545ag5645sdfa55sdf45fv5er5cfvg5s45
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: yes you are right but i am not getting this from user input and i know 100% whats inside N100

Comment: add a try catch block for that line. is N100 column varchar type?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the correct constructor for the SqlCommand? It seems to me that you are atleast missing:

```
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1
```

You might as well do that in the constructor when you create the command:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT S2 FROM CDUSR WHERE N100 = " + N100.ToString()), sqlConnection1)
```

a using block would be nice as well:

```
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(blah blah)) { cmd.ExecuteScalar; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess Visual Studio stops debugging because your code throws an exception (your SqlCommand is not associated with the SqlConnection you use) ... maybe you have "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" disabled in your "Exception Settings" so you don't actually see the exception being thrown ...